# Variable set in class but empty when called in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page which in the code behind imports and runs the class "ldap.GetUser()" in the Page_Load event.

When I breakpoint the *class* it populates the variable "strUserName" with a value.

However when I call this value in the code behind page like this:

```
strCurrentUserName = ldap.strUsername
```

It's returning Nothing.

Seeing as the variable is being set in the class and the class is running - why is the code behind not able get the value of of the "strUserName" variable?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: *However when I call this value in the code behind page* - Which is when? In an event handler (e.g. button click)? More code is needed to diagnose the problem but my suspicion is that you are trying to access a private variable that was initialised in a different instance of the class (i.e. a previous page load).

Comment: sounds like a potential scoping issue, can you post how (and perhaps more importantly where) your variables are being instantiated, and how/where you're attempting to access ldap?